# PHP: header redirect, after simple array shuffle

Tags: php, arrays, header

Ive got this simple php code:

```
<?php
  $links = array('http://link1.com', 'http://link2.com',);
  shuffle($links); 
  header("Location: $links[0]");
  exit;
?>
```

I want to randomize redirect link, using this simple array. Ive got two different servers on two different hostings. It works fine on one of these hosting and on localhost apache, but doesnt work on the second hosting. What might be the issue? Different php settings? Array and shuffle works, because I can echo te links, but there is a problem with header.

Comment: Add error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1); in the start of your file and tell us what error you get if you get any.

Comment: This didnt provide any error at all.

Comment: And what do _“doesnt work”_ and _“but there is a problem with header”_ actually mean …?

Comment: It means that it doesn't work and there is a problem with the header. Don't bother to take a while to understand this statement.

Comment: Instead of trying to be sarcastic, please go read [ask] instead. _“It doesn’t work”_ is not considered to be a valid problem description, and _“there is a problem with the header”_ does not give us any useful information either.

Comment: And you are being niggling. No one exept you had a problem to understand it and help me. php is not my branch, but I had this problem I stucked with. Im also not a native speaker. It doesnt work, means that it doesn't redirect, but I think you know it. Don't be a 0/1 thinker. Anyway the code I shown is complete and I don't use sessions. It "works" on the other hosting, so instead of wasting time to instruct me, use your knowlege to explain this. Anyway thanks...

Comment: _“No one exept you had a problem to understand it and help me”_ – again, that the answer “worked” is just coincidence. Neither did the person answering give any indication as to how this might be related to sessions (which it is most likely not one bit), nor did you yourself understand why/how this seemingly “fixed” the problem (as you stated yourself in comments). This is not about someone “understanding” your problem in the first place, because there is not enough information to properly analyze this – the person answering just took a shot in the dark and hit the target purely randomly.

Comment: And that your code works on one sever, but not on another is another indicator that sessions are not the problem here – and they are not the solution either. Starting a session just seems to somehow “fix” the problem – rather not even fix it, but just change the circumstances under which it occurs in the first place. But if you’re happy with that kind of “solution” – well, that’s up to you. Hope you realize what kind of unnecessary overhead this creates for a site that otherwise doesn’t even make use of sessions. Anyone serious about their stuff would rather try and find the real cause though.

Comment: It is a solution I wanted - it "works":) and that was the idea posting here. I need this code up for only 2 days so I really don't care if this a proper way to fix it, because I have a tracking system to do this kind of A/B switching for me, and actually I cannot use it. As I said I'm in different stuff than php coding so i really want it to just work... It is really so relevant info to help fix it? I also said that I wanna to understand it, so please tell, what information is essential to analyze this issue, because you have written so many so far, but nothing useful yet. Do you see my point?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

<strike>Do you have</strike> Try putting:

```
   session_start()
```

at the beginning of your file? This worked for me a while ago

Updated due to one user not liking the wording of my answer... (See strike through text)

Comment: What are you talking about? I have asked an almost identical question before and someone told me to put session_start() at the top of the page and the problem was sorted. Anyone can read my answer and figure out that if you don't have session_start() at the beginning of your file, you should try it. So this is absolutely an answer to the question.

Comment: This is absolutely _not_ an answer to the question, because the code shown a) does not _use_ sessions, and b) does not _need_ a session.

Comment: It works now with the session_start(). Simple solution, but I dont understand it, and why I need it on this particular server? I forgot to mention that simple 'header' without the array shuffle works fine.

Comment: Glad it's working for you! Not bad considering I didn't provide an answer to the question ;)

Comment: @FilipB: If this “works” with session_start and not without, then there must be more to it than in the few lines of code you have shown. It might f.e. be that a session you have already been using before does not get picked up correctly in the new script that is called via the redirect (but then you totally failed to mention this). So if this answer “fixes” the problem, than that was by pure chance.

Comment: Waa waa waaaa lighten up. I saw he was using php and guessed that he might have forgot to mention details (or may not have knew he had to mention certain details) and answered the question. Worst case scenario is my answer wouldn't have helped and he can just ignore it - no harm done. Best case scenario - I have helped this user (and maybe other people in future) with their problem.